# How to find internal Column name in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, image

I am attempting to use a migration tool that will extract properties from images (drone photos) and map them to columns in SharePoint Online.  I'm focused on one property just to get the ball rolling.

In the image, I'm confident Altitude is represented as GPSAltitude.  I've created a column called Altitude in SharePoint, but am not having luck.  The tool requires that a txt file contain the property in the image be mapped to the corresponding SharePoint internal column name.  Based on the examples given in the txt file, I'm guessing I have the internal SharePoint column name wrong.  Please see the image below:

[image]

Comment: You can get the internal name of column from Column settings. Open column from list settings and see for "Field=" in url at very last. you will find the correct internal name after = and before next query string parameter. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/75ca6fab-56f3-4bf4-aae0-2d29821778a2/how-to-get-internal-names-of-columns-in-sharepoint-lists?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the SharePoint Client Browser (SPCB) uses the SharePoint API (a.k.a. CSOM) to connect to a remote SharePoint site collection and shows the site structure with related properties and values.

**Download**: [SharePoint Online Client Browser v4.3](https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb/releases/tag/v4.3)

More information: [SharePoint Client Browser (SPCB)](https://github.com/bramdejager/spcb)

Comment: This is a fantastic tool!

Answer (score 2):

Step to see Internal column name:
1.Open list.(whatever your list is) 
2.Click on gear icon located on top right side. 
3.Click on **List Settings** 
4.Then scroll down, you will find column names in left side of screen. 
5.Click on column name. 
6.Then see its URL 
i am attaching screenshot for your reference.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a more broadly available solution that anyone can access versus downloading a tool

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the internal name of your SharePoint online column, via SharePoint UI (modern experience as well as classic experience), SharePoint REST API, PnP PowerShell or CLI for Microsoft 365, etc.

You can use endpoint like below to get the internal name using SharePoint REST API:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/fields?$select=Title,InternalName&$filter=Title eq 'Created By'
```

You can find other ways in this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)